# Does Sendgrid require mail gem and how to set it up with action mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, sendgrid

Heroku docs says:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid#ruby-rails

```
To send out emails through SendGrid, you need to configure the Mail class to have the correct values:
require 'mail'

Mail.defaults do
  delivery_method :smtp, {
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => '587',
    :domain => 'heroku.com',
    :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
end
```

Neither the Mail gem docs or heroku specify clearly where the Mail class should be and how to configure it.

In the past I have just used Action Mailer something like this

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'careerswitch.me@gmail.com'

  # Subject can be set in your I18n file at config/locales/en.yml
  # with the following lookup:
  #
  #   en.user_mailer.signup_confirmation.subject

  def signup_confirmation(user,subject_param='Welcome!')
    @user = user

    mail to: user.email,
         subject: subject_param  do |format|
         #format.text {render __method__}
         format.html {render __method__}
    end
  end

end
```

Any good example on what has changed and how do I setup sendgrid on Herouku/Rails4.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku provide add on for sendgrid.
https://elements.heroku.com/addons/sendgrid

By adding this it will automatically set environment variables for you i.e 
SENDGRID_USERNAME
SENDGRID_PASSWORD

After provisioning the add-on you have to put this into production.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
 :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
 :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
 :domain => 'appname.herokuapp.com',
 :address => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
 :port => 587,
 :authentication => :plain,
 :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Mailer class will remain same as normally used.

Answer (score 0):

These are initializer  settings. There *should* be a generator for that, but I think there isn't. At least last time I did it manually.

1. Go to  `yourappdirectory/config/initializers`
2. Create a file named  `mail.rb`
3. Paste the code above there

That's all. Once you configure it, you'll be good to go.